# Laravel Eloquent doesn't work with Cache

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, closures, anonymous-function

I'm trying to cache a query in laravel in a model.
My code was :

```php
foreach(Building::where('village', '=', $village->id)->get() as $building)
            {
```

So I did it like this:

```php
$buildingCache = Cache::remember('test123456', 60, function()
{
    return Building::where('village', '=', $id)->get();
});
foreach ($buildingCache as $bjdkfjksk)...............
```

And a strange error appears :

```
Undefined variable: id
```

But I'm sure this var is defined, I use it before...

Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use closure, you need to add `use` to use any variable inside closure this way:

```
$buildingCache = Cache::remember('test123456', 60, function() use ($id)
{
    return Building::where('village', '=', $id)->get();
});
```